# Add to the ODE solution at some timestep

Tags: differential-equations

I have two ODE:

```
ysol1 = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 30}];
ysol2 = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], 
    y[30] == ysol1[30] + 2}, y, {x, 30, 60}];
Plot[ysol1[x], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[ysol2[x], {x, 30, 60}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The second one is the same as the first, I just added 2 to the final timestep value and continued calculations. 
The question is: how can I wright the same withing one equeation? Something like:

```
 ysol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1, y[30] == y[30]+2}, 
       y, {x, 0, 60}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `WhenEvent`

```
Y = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] ==1,WhenEvent[x == 30 , y[x] -> y[x] + 2]}, y, {x, 0, 60}]
Plot[Y[t], {t, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]